# How to wrap an async method in python as a normal method?

Tags: python, async-await

In python it seems you have to use `telnetlib3` when you want to work with telnet. Unfortunately, this is an "async" module and you have to use "await" and "async" everywhere ...

Basically I have created a small wrapper of the `telnet3` module as follows:

```
class Telnet3:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    async def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection(self.host, self.port)
        data = await asyncio.wait_for(self.reader.read(4096), timeout=2)
        return data

    async def write(self, command):
        self.writer.write(command + "\r\n")
        time.sleep(5)
        data = await asyncio.wait_for(self.reader.read(4096), timeout=5)
        return data
```

which I want to use in a different code WITHOUT any `async`, `await` etc, stuff. I just want to do something like

```
from mytelnetlib3 import Telnet3

mytelnet = Telnet3("localhost", 9000)
mytelnet.connect()
reply = mytelnet.write("some command")
print(reply)
```

How to do that? How to change my `Telnet3` class so I can use the functionality without `async`, `await` and that stuff?

**As an alternative**: Is there ANY other module/library I can use to access/use the `telnet` protocol to communicate with devices? Please do not suggest [exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript), this does not seem to work. Except you can provide the above class using exscript. That also would help.

Comment: If it was that easy, `async` wouldn't exist.

Comment: the async code needs an event loop to drive it. You can't wrap that in sync code and expect it to work.

Comment: [PEP 594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#deprecated-modules) suggests [Exscript](https://exscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), if you don't want to use telnetlib3.

Comment: I was looking into Exscript, does not seem to work at all.

Comment: Take a look at `pexpect`. It's the appropriate library for automating interactive sessions.

Comment: @Barmar Yes maybe that is a good choice. I finally get some replies! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `async-await` syntax implicitly requires that there is an event loop running in the main thread of your program, thus, there is no method to convert an `async-await` function to a "normal" function.

However, if you can afford running such an event loop in your program and you simply want avoid propagating the `async-await` syntax to every function in your program using the TellNet functionality, you can use `loop.run_until_complete()` method to convert an async function to a regular blocking one:

```py
import asyncio


async def some_async_func(i: int) -> int:
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return i


def some_func(i: int, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> int:
    return loop.run_until_complete(some_async_func(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    result = some_func(42, loop)
    print(result)
```

With this method, you could wrap `Telnet3.connect()` and `Telnet3.write()` to be regular blocking method and expresse your desired code. However, you have to manually create the event loop and manage its lifetime properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when doing this on a windows computer I get an error `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid` (without a line number). How can this be fixed?

Comment: That is weird, maybe try to update Python.

Comment: same issue as reported by @Alex on Windows with python 3.11.6. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Does adding `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` before creating the event loop solves the issue? You can try solutions presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412754/python-asyncio-errors-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid-and-runtim) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255332/exception-event-loop-is-closed-with-aiohttp-and-asyncio-in-python-3-8) threads.